# Ajax request bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am teaching myself how to code, so this might be fairly clumsy code.
This is a website that is mainly a photo viewer with an introduction which is a short video. This video is hidden after it plays. The navigation loads various pages and I am doing this with AJAX. I am having the problem that the AJAX is loading back the video for a split second.

The best way to see it is if you go to the page.

http://maxruiz-parana.com

Here is my code. I only include the html and javascript files and from the javascript file you only really need to look at the first 80 lines or so.

When you navigate through the site you get the annoying video back. Can anyone help. Thanks.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Max Ruiz | Parana</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="allIntro">
  <div>
    <video playsinline autoplay loop id="bgvid" class="visible" >
      <source src="Images/PARANA/newIntro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

  <div id="presentacion">
    <h1>PARANA</h1>
    <h2>PHOTOGRAPHIES DE MAX RUIZ</h2>
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="header">
  <div id="title"><h1>MAX RUIZ <span id="parana">PARANÁ</span></h1></div>
      <nav class="cf" id="menu">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery2.html" id="gall">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" id="home" class="current">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
</div>

<section id="content">

<div id="container">

  <div id="imagewrap">
    <img src="Images/PARANA/Image1.jpg" id="front" class="bigImage" />

    <div id="info">Verde</div>


    <div id="previous" class="buttons"></div>

    <div id="next" class="buttons"></div>
  </div>

</div>

</section> <!-- end of container -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1;
    document.getElementById("front").src = "Images/PARANA/Image" + random + ".jpg";

    $( "#content" ).hide();

    $( '#header' ).hide();

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        counter = random;
        displayArrows();
        updateInfo(counter);


    //set up video and text//

        var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");

        function stopVideo() {
        vid.pause();
        $( '#presentacion').delay(3000).hide();
        vid.parent().delay(3000).hide();
        $( '#allIntro' ).hide();
        }

        setTimeout(stopVideo, 3000);

        function showSite() {
        $( '#header' ).delay(1500).fadeIn(2000);
        $( "#content" ).delay(1500).fadeIn(2000);
        }

        showSite();


    //once content loaded

    $( 'body,html' ).dblclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //main page functionality nav//

    $( document ).on('click', 'nav a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = this.href;
        $( "nav a.current" ).removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $( '#container' ).remove();
        $( '#content').load(url + ' #content', function(){

            if (url == 'http://maxruiz-parana.com/contact.html'){
                $( 'title' ).text('Paraná | Contact');
            }
            else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-parana.com/gallery.html'){
                $( 'title' ).text('Paraná | Gallery');
            }
            else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-parana.com/about.html'){
                $( 'title' ).text('Paraná | About');
                $( '#english' ).hide();
            }
            else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-parana.com/bio.html'){
                $( 'title' ).text('Paraná | Bio');
            }
            else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-parana.com/gallery.html'){
                $( 'title' ).text('Max Ruiz | Paraná');
            }
            counter = random;
            $( '#previous' ).css('display', 'none');
        }).hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });




    //main page functionality buttons//

    counter = random;

    $( document ).on('click', '.buttons', function(e){
        if (counter < 1 || counter > 31) {return false;}
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = e.target.id;
        if (id == "next" && counter < 31){counter++;
        } else if (id == "previous" && counter > 1){counter--;}


    $('#front').fadeOut(500, function() {
            getImage(function(){
                $('#front').fadeIn(500);
            });
    });

    updateInfo(counter);

    });

    getImage = function (cb) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("front").src = img.src;
        cb();
        };
      img.src = "Images/PARANA/Image" + counter + ".jpg";

      displayArrows();

    }

    function displayArrows() {
        if (counter == 1) {
            $( '#previous' ).css('display', 'none');
        }
        else if (counter > 1 && counter < 31) {
            $( '#previous' ).css('display', 'block');
            $( '#next' ).css('display', 'block');
        }
        else if (counter == 31) {
          $( '#next' ).css('display', 'none');
        }
    }





    // gallery functionality//

    $( document ).on('click', '.littleImages', function(e){

        $( '#gall' ).removeClass("current");
        $( '#home' ).addClass("current");

        var imageSource = $(this).attr('src');

    // find the not square picture from the square source

        var n = imageSource.lastIndexOf('/');

        var result = imageSource.substring(n + 1);

        var imageSourceFinal = 'Images/PARANA/' + result;


    // find the counter in order to know if it's the last or the first picture and hide corr arrow

        counter = imageSource.match(/\d+/g);

        $( '#container' ).remove();

        $( '#content').load('index.html' + ' #content', function(){

            $( '#front' ).attr('src', imageSourceFinal);

            if (counter == 1) { $( '#previous' ).css('display', 'none');}
            if (counter == 31){ $( '#next' ).css('display', 'none');}

            // updateInfo(counter);
            testFunction(counter[0]);

        }).hide().fadeIn('slow');

    });



    // legend for pictures functionality

    $( document ).on('mouseover', '#front', function(){
        $( '#front').fadeTo(300, 0.3);
        $( '#info' ).fadeTo(300, 1);
    });

    $( document ).on('mouseout', '#front', function(){
        $( '#front').fadeTo(300, 1);
        $( '#info' ).fadeTo(300, 0);
    });

    function testFunction(number){

        switch(number) {
            case "1":
              $( '#info').text('Verde');
              break;
            case "2":
                $( '#info').text('Pardo');
                break;
            case "3":
              $( '#info').text('Ivinhema');
              break;
            case "4":
                $( '#info').text('Guayquiraró');
                break;
            case "5":
              $( '#info').text('Monday');
              break;
            case "6":
                $( '#info').text('Paranapanema');
                break;
            case "7":
              $( '#info').text('Salado');
              break;
            case "8":
                $( '#info').text('Piquiri');
                break;
            case "9":
              $( '#info').text('Gualeguay');
              break;
            case "10":
                $( '#info').text('Negro');
                break;
            case "11":
              $( '#info').text('Santa Lucía');
              break;
            case "12":
                $( '#info').text('Ivai');
                break;
            case "13":
              $( '#info').text('Corriente');
              break;
            case "14":
                $( '#info').text('Luján');
                break;
            case "15":
              $( '#info').text('Paraguay');
              break;
            case "16":
                $( '#info').text('Iguazú');
                break;
            case "17":
              $( '#info').text('Aguapey');
              break;
            case "18":
                $( '#info').text('Victoria');
                break;
            case "19":
              $( '#info').text('Tieté');
              break;
            case "20":
                $( '#info').text('Pardo');
                break;
            case "21":
                $( '#info').text('Yabeberi');
                break;
            case "22":
                $( '#info').text('Ñacaguazú');
                break;
            case "23":
                $( '#info').text('Tapenagá');
            case "24":
                $( '#info').text('Arazá');
                break;
            case "25":
                $( '#info').text('Tupicuá');
                break;
            case "26":
                $( '#info').text('Añiá');
                break;
            case "27":
                $( '#info').text('Tamanduatey');
                break;
            case "28":
                $( '#info').text('Aguapey');
                break;
        }
    }

    function updateInfo(number) {

        switch(number) {
            case 1:
              $( '#info').text('Verde');
              break;
            case 2:
                $( '#info').text('Pardo');
                break;
            case 3:
              $( '#info').text('Ivinhema');
              break;
            case 4:
                $( '#info').text('Guayquiraró');
                break;
            case 5:
              $( '#info').text('Monday');
              break;
            case 6:
                $( '#info').text('Paranapanema');
                break;
            case 7:
              $( '#info').text('Salado');
              break;
            case 8:
                $( '#info').text('Piquiri');
                break;
            case 9:
              $( '#info').text('Gualeguay');
              break;
            case 10:
                $( '#info').text('Negro');
                break;
            case 11:
              $( '#info').text('Santa Lucía');
              break;
            case 12:
                $( '#info').text('Ivai');
                break;
            case 13:
              $( '#info').text('Corriente');
              break;
            case 14:
                $( '#info').text('Luján');
                break;
            case 15:
              $( '#info').text('Paraguay');
              break;
            case 16:
                $( '#info').text('Iguazú');
                break;
            case 17:
              $( '#info').text('Aguapey');
              break;
            case 18:
                $( '#info').text('Victoria');
                break;
            case 19:
              $( '#info').text('Tieté');
              break;
            case 20:
                $( '#info').text('Pardo');
                break;
            case 21:
                $( '#info').text('Yabeberi');
                break;
            case 22:
                $( '#info').text('Ñacaguazú');
                break;
            case 23:
                $( '#info').text('Tapenagá');
            case 24:
                $( '#info').text('Arazá');
                break;
            case 25:
                $( '#info').text('Tupicuá');
                break;
            case 26:
                $( '#info').text('Añiá');
                break;
            case 27:
                $( '#info').text('Tamanduatey');
                break;
            case 28:
                $( '#info').text('Aguapey');
                break;
        }
    }


// About functionality

$( document ).on('click', '#enButton', function(){
    $( '#english' ).fadeIn();
    $( '#french' ).fadeOut();
});

$( document ).on('click', '#frButton', function(){
    $( '#english' ).fadeOut();
    $( '#french' ).fadeIn();
});



});
```

Comment: Because you're fading out then you're fading in. You need to cross fade. You need two layers on top of each other, load your new content in the bottom layer, then fade out the top layer, and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript is throwing an error on this line:

```
vid.parent().delay(3000).hide()
```

> TypeError: vid.parent is not a function. (In 'vid.parent()', 'vid.parent' is undefined)

This will prevent the video hiding as you want it to.

The error happens because you are calling a Jquery method on a plain html node. Also, I'm not sure that `delay()` will work like this. It's meant for adding a delay between Jquery methods. I think this should work better:

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $("#bgvid").parent().hide()
    }, 3000);
```